# Shoreline clipping in Carto

Tags: postgis, carto

I'm trying to clip a map of [Oakland City Council Districts](https://data.oaklandnet.com/City-Government/City-of-Oakland-Council-Districts/g7vb-tiyh) to the shoreline. Carto even has a [nice walk through](https://carto.com/blog/tiger-shoreline-clip/) of how one could (theoretically) accomplish this, but I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

If I have a map of US States, and a map of Oakland city council districts, I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT oakland.*, states.the_geom
FROM oakland_city_council_districts AS oakland,
 US_states_shapes AS states 
WHERE ST_Intersects(oakland.the_geom, states.the_geom)
```

But that particular query just gets me an error: `column reference the_geom is ambiguous` -- if I pull out `states.the_geom` I get the shapes, but they aren't cropped at all.

Realizing, with help in the answers here, that I should be using `ST_Intersection` (not `ST_Intersects`) I revised my query to:

```
SELECT oakland.councilmem, oakland.dist, oakland.fullname,
ST_Intersection(oakland.the_geom, states.the_geom) AS the_geom 
FROM oakland_city_council_districts AS oakland, 
US_states_shapes AS states WHERE oakland.dist = 3
```

But that query finds nothing.

So how can I use the single California polygon in my `US_states_shapes` table to trim the Oakland City Council Districts to the coastline?

Answer (score 1):

> But that particular query just gets me an error: column reference
>   the_geom is ambiguous

I think you are getting the error because you have two `the_geom` columns in your SELECT list. One from `oakland.*`, the other from `states.the_geom`. You can drop one of them or use an alias on one of them.

> -- if I pull out states.the_geom I get the shapes, but they aren't cropped at all.

This is because you haven't actually performed the cropping. Your filter

```
WHERE ST_Intersects(oakland.the_geom, states.the_geom)
```

only filters out polygons that have no intersection with `states.the_geom`. To find and return the actual intersection between `oakland.the_geom` and  `states.the_geom`, you will need e.g., [ST_Intersection](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html). Quoting documentation:

> ST_Intersection — (T) Returns a geometry that represents the shared
>   portion of geomA and geomB.

Comment: Ahh, ST_Intersection vs ST_Intersects is a great clue, but I'm still not all the way there. I'll keep trying to refine my query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter by the states, not the district no? You can try this query on this [simple viewer](http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/raw/d945737eb42ca83654301e66dac365cb/) where I used a world borders dataset to do the clip. You can compare with just selecting everything from `oakland_districts`.

```
select o.cartodb_id,
       ST_Intersection(
         w.the_geom_webmercator,
         o.the_geom_webmercator
       ) as the_geom_webmercator
  from oakland_districts o,
       world_borders_hd w
 where w.adm0_a3 = 'USA'
```

[image]